Catching a large reaction mass in space
Suppose we have a long, cylindrical spaceship in free fall in space.  Another spacecraft is nearby for observing the cylindrical craft; also in free fall so we can determine when the cylindrical spacecraft moves relative to the observer.
At the front of the tube there is a large block of metal, suppose we chuck it down the tube such that it doesn't hit the sides.  We now have a very odd rocket.  Nonetheless, the cylinder should move in the opposite direction and our observer notes it does so for many meters.
Instead of allowing the block of metal to exit, it is caught at the other end of the cylinder.  Conservation of Momentum should dictate our cylindrical spacecraft plus block of metal will cease moving, but the whole system should remain the many meters away from its starting point as noted by the observer.
Correct?

The energy exerted when the block is chucked is transferred into kinetic energy to induce movement in the tube. After the final impact, the energy is transferred back to the block and it will continue like this forever.

Yes, that is correct. Note that the center of mass of the ship + block system does not change. The position of the ship changes one direction and the position of the block changes the opposite direction.
